# How to identify user after he logged in?

Tags: authentication, cookies, x509certificate

This is not a programming question, but I'm not sure where to ask it.
I have a sign-in page, after user enters his credentials I generate a token for him, and he can select a site from a list. After that, he is redirected to that site. The problem is - I can't store his token in cookies and in header. How can I identify a user after redirect? I'm thinking about certificates(not familiar with them, but as I understood I can identify a user via certificate). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cross site requests:
You can make http requests with Javascript to others domains if they allow cross requests to your domain. These requests are filled with cookies etc like a normal request from the navigator. You just have to make your auto login trick on a separated web page and allow cross domain requests from your other domains to this page (with headers) and on your other websites, you can make a request to this page and then get the informations you want.